# Mongoose default w/ findOneAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  displayName: { type: String, required: true },
  registered: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: false }
});
```

I then try to insert and object using findOneAndUpdate:

```
  var user = {
    displayName: "Test User"
  }

  User.findOneAndUpdate({username: "test"}, user, {new: true, upsert: true}, function(err, newUser) {
    callback(err, newUser);
  });
```

The user gets correctly created (on the first attempt, since it does not exist).  However the registered field does not get set to false.  Should this happen when I do a findOneAndUpdate?

Result from mongo query:

```
> db.users.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56255f415641ace1204de658"),
    "username" : "Test",
    "displayName" : "Test User"
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Found this in mongoose docs:

> findAndModify helpers support limited defaults and validation. You can
>   enable these by setting the setDefaultsOnInsert and runValidators
>   options, respectively.

In case anyone else runs into this.

```
 var user = {
    displayName: "Test User"
  }

  User.findOneAndUpdate({username: "test"}, user, {setDefaultsOnInsert: true, new: true, upsert: true}, function(err, newUser) {
    callback(err, newUser);
  });
```